# Trouble executing a JAR file through Command Prompt

Tags: java, jar, cmd

So I am trying to create and run my first .jar file.
The code I'm using is a simple Hello World GUI and here's the source:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class HelloWorldGUI2 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      HelloWorldDisplay displayPanel = new HelloWorldDisplay();
      JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
      ButtonHandler listener = new ButtonHandler();
      okButton.addActionListener(listener);

      JPanel content = new JPanel();
      content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      content.add(displayPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      content.add(okButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      JFrame window = new JFrame("GUI Test");
      window.setContentPane(content);
      window.setSize(250,100);
      window.setLocation(100,100);
      window.setVisible(true);

   }


   private static class HelloWorldDisplay extends JPanel {
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(g);
         g.drawString( "Hello World!", 20, 30 );
      }
   }

   private static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         System.exit(0);
      }
   }
}
```

I compile the code in Command prompt using *javac* and it gives me the three class files.

I can then execute it using *java* command and it runs perfectly.

How ever I want to create a .jar file and run from that.

I use:

*jar cfe HelloWorldGUI2.jar HelloWorldGUI2 HelloWorldGUI2.class*

To create the .jar file with the main class targetted. And then I use:

*java -jar app.jar*

to run it. But it gives an exception error. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: what exception, please be more specific.

Comment: The compiler produces 3 class files. Why do you only add 1 of them to the jar file? Do you really think the 2 other ones are useless?